# Can floor-ing a rounded number gives a different answer than the rounded number?

Tags: floating-point, rounding, precision, ieee-754, floor

Am I correct that floor(round($number)) is not necessarily equal to round($number) assuming that "round" returns a double?

As an example, imagine that $number = 123456.9999999999999999.  I'm guessing that "round" will be a no-op, since $number is already as close as possible to 123457. 
 "floor" would then yield 123456.

Is this correct or is there something about "floor" or "round" that prevents this?

Comment: The result of `round` should never be a non-integer value.

Comment: "round" returns a double in C, PHP, and many other languages.

Oliver, are you saying that for non-large integers they can be represented exactly by the double?

Comment: I'm saying there's never a case where a non-integer value **can** be represented by a `double`, but the nearest integer value **can't** be represented.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the way that IEEE-754 floating-point representation works,<sup>1</sup> it's not possible for a non-integer value (e.g. 123456.9999999999999999) to be representable and the nearest integer value (e.g. 123457) to be unrepresentable.

Thus in a sane implementation, the result of `round` should always be an integer value.  Indeed, in the case of C, the language standard mandates this.<sup>2</sup>

Thus in such a sane language, `floor(round(x))` and `round(x)` are always the same.

---

<sub>1. IEEE-754 is overwhelmingly common now.  Technically, it may be possible to construct a floating-point system where this **isn't** true, but I doubt such a system exists in practice.</sub>

<sub>2. Your other example, PHP, has a [sketchy "decimal precision" feature](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) which makes me skeptical that the same guarantee applies!  Indeed, the [implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/math.c#L129) involves all sorts of mad stuff, including *converting to a string and back*.</sub>

Comment: I'd quibble with the "not possible": there's no reason one couldn't create a floating-point format in which not all small integers are exactly representable. It just wouldn't be a particularly nice format, and wouldn't match any of the existing real-world formats that I've seen.

Comment: @MarkDickinson - Possibly true.  Though the question was tagged with "ieee-754", so I'm answering in the context of that.  I'll update my answer to make that explicit, though :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed that tag. Absolutely agreed that it's not possible for IEEE 754 formats.

Answer (score 0):

> Can floor-ing a rounded number gives a different answer than the rounded number?

Sometimes looking at corners cases can expose a counter example.

```
void rtest(double x) {
  double y1 = floor(round(x));
  double y2 = round(x);
  printf("%d %- 14e %- 14e %- 14e\n", y1 != y2, x, y1, y2);
}

int main(void) {
  double x[] = { 0.0, DBL_TRUE_MIN, DBL_MIN, 1.0, 3.14, 3.99, DBL_MAX, 1.0/0.0, 0.0/0.0};
  for (unsigned i=0; i< sizeof x/sizeof x[0]; i++) {
    rtest(x[i]);
    rtest(-x[i]);
  }
}
```

Output

```
0  0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00 
0 -0.000000e+00  -0.000000e+00  -0.000000e+00 
0  4.940656e-324  0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00 
0 -4.940656e-324 -0.000000e+00  -0.000000e+00 
0  2.225074e-308  0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00 
0 -2.225074e-308 -0.000000e+00  -0.000000e+00 
0  1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00 
0 -1.000000e+00  -1.000000e+00  -1.000000e+00 
0  3.140000e+00   3.000000e+00   3.000000e+00 
0 -3.140000e+00  -3.000000e+00  -3.000000e+00 
0  3.990000e+00   4.000000e+00   4.000000e+00 
0 -3.990000e+00  -4.000000e+00  -4.000000e+00 
0  1.797693e+308  1.797693e+308  1.797693e+308
0 -1.797693e+308 -1.797693e+308 -1.797693e+308
0  inf            inf            inf          
0 -inf           -inf           -inf          
1 -nan           -nan           -nan          
1  nan            nan            nan
```

When dealing with ieee-754 numbers, `floor(round(x)) != round(x)` is true or ("not necessarily equal" per OP's quesiton) when `x` is Not-A-Number.

Otherwise the result of a `round()` is always an integer value or infinity and `floor-ing does not change the value.

I checked various rounding  modes and found  the same result.